# Merge [ceil] and [ceiling] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are currently 69 questions in the tag [ceiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ceiling), all is about the mathematical ceiling (what else can it be?) but it doesn't have a wiki

There are more questions (154) in the tag [ceil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ceil), but probably just because most languages use `ceil` instead if `ceiling` for the function name

IMHO [ceiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ceiling) should be added as a synonym for [ceil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ceil)

Comment: Users tag with the function name, not the concept.  It is in fact "ceiling" in [c#], [r], [excel].  The concept is too tricky when languages might or might not support a base10 floating point type and the never-the-same problem with floating point rounding.

Comment: Is this even a useful tag? Are there experts in [ceiling]?

Comment: What about when people need to program the [ceiling]s in their smart homes?

Comment: @JL2210 that way they should tag [tag:smart-home] instead of each specific thing in their homes like [tag:door], [tag:floor]

Comment: @phuclv It was a joke...

Comment: @Kevin useful or not, people are using it. A lot. And there are tons of math masters here

Comment: Just like you tag [smart-home] instead of every little thing separately, perhaps it makes more sense to have [math] or [rounding] instead of [floor], [ceil], [round],... If people are using an overly specific tag, we can always fix it with synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

I say make [ceiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ceiling) a synonym of [ceil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ceil).  `ceil` has more questions and a tag wiki.  Both tags have questions that refer to the other name.

- [Tagged ceil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301864/why-isnt-math-ceiling-rounding-up-my-number-java) but refers to `ceiling`
- [Tagged ceiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117170/when-will-static-casting-the-result-of-ceil-compromise-the-result) but refers to `ceil`

There are also a handful<sup>1</sup> of questions tagged with both.

<sup>1</sup>Well, [Count Rugen's](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093779/characters/nm0001302) right hand.